# 2 content types and reference

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8.9.

I have 2 content types **Teacher** and **Subject**. Teacher has **2 reference fields** of content type Subject (first one is the subject which the teacher is teaching and second one is the subject which the teacher lectures).

My desired functionality is that the teacher chooses Subjects which he teaches or lectures and then **teacher's name automatically shows in corresponding Subject** under corresponding title (teacher or lecturer) with link to teacher's page.

I am a total newbie in Drupal as I am doing this as my school work, so please be patient with me :)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! On Drupal, the name of the user who created a node is already shown; that username is a link to the user account, if the logged-in user has the permission to see other user's accounts.

Comment: You can find many examples where you can learn about showing "backwards" relationship info. Here's one with other links: [How to check if a referenced entity is being used in other places?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287345/how-to-check-if-a-referenced-entity-is-being-used-in-other-places/287352#287352), [List Parent links on Child nodes using Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/262425/referencing-nodes-reciprocally/262463#262463), https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/276914/how-do-i-show-a-list-of-nodes-referenced-by-a-field/276954#276954.

Comment: I just answered a very simiar Q: [Contextual Filter Path Alias](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/302534/contextual-filter-path-alias/302546#302546). Basically you need to create 2 lists of Teachers, one that uses Subject as Contextual Filter, and the other that uses Lectures as contextual filter.